# Error when deploying Spring boot Application on WebSphere Application server 8.5.5

Tags: spring, websphere, boot

When deploying a spring boot application on websphere application server WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.11 [ND 8.5.5.11 cf111649.01] and Java version = 1.8.0, I get this exception :

```
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: IWAE0012E An IO exception occurred loading com/sopra/savbackend/service/dto**/SavSimulationResultDTO$SavSimulationResultDTOBuilder.class**
```

I don't know why this problem, I think is about innerClass ($).

You can find below the detailled log :

```
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: IWAE0012E An IO exception occurred loading com/sopra/savbackend/service/dto/SavSimulationResultDTO$SavSimulationResultDTOBuilder.class
                at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl.join(WsComponentImpl.java:432)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCUList(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:1277)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:274)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationServerImpl.start(ApplicationServerImpl.java:252)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:540)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:316)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:229)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:702)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
                at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
                at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
                at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
                at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
                at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
                at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
                at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:402)
                at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:165)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: IWAE0012E An IO exception occurred loading com/sopra/savbackend/service/dto/SavSimulationResultDTO$SavSimulationResultDTOBuilder.class
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:433)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
                at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5397)
                at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5613)
                at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984)
                at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
                at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: IWAE0012E An IO exception occurred loading com/sopra/savbackend/service/dto/SavSimulationResultDTO$SavSimulationResultDTOBuilder.class
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:914)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
                ... 18 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: IWAE0012E An IO exception occurred loading com/sopra/savbackend/service/dto/SavSimulationResultDTO$SavSimulationResultDTOBuilder.class
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:186)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
                ... 20 more
`Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ArchiveRuntimeException: IWAE0012E An IO exception occurred loading com/sopra/savbackend/service/dto/SavSimulationResultDTO$SavSimulationResultDTOBuilder.class
                at `org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.util.ArchiveFileDynamicClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ArchiveFileDynamicClassLoader.java:1463)
                at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.info.impl.ClassLoaderCache.searchAllClassLoaders(ClassLoaderCache.java:349)
                at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.info.impl.ClassInfoManagerImpl.scanClassResource(ClassInfoManagerImpl.java:194)
                at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.info.impl.ClassInfoCache.scanClassResource(ClassInfoCache.java:155)
                at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.info.impl.ClassInfoCache.resolveClassInfo(ClassInfoCache.java:854)
                at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.info.impl.ClassInfoManagerImpl.resolveClassInfo(ClassInfoManagerImpl.java:274)
                at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.info.impl.DelayedClassInfo.getClassInfo(DelayedClassInfo.java:245)
                at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.info.impl.DelayedClassInfo.getAllInterfaceNames(DelayedClassInfo.java:365)
                at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.info.impl.DelayedClassInfo.isInstanceOf(DelayedClassInfo.java:46
```

I expect to deploy a spring boot application on a websphere application server.
For information : I did many changes on my pom file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please show your full pom and your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. Which Spring Boot version are you using? WebSphere 8.5 is pretty old and supports only Servlet API 3.0 (so if you have a too new version of Spring Boot it probably won't work).

Comment: I changed the version of spring boot to 2.4.0 , and now I have another problem :[2/21/23 17:22:20:187 WET] 0016d675 WSModuleDescr E   WSWS7011E: The configuration for the savbackend-0.0.5.war application module cannot load correctly. 
The following error occurred:  com.ibm.ws.metadata.annotations.AnnotationException: Annotation processing failed for class:  module-info.class

Comment: Looks like you are compiling with an newer version of java then supported by your websphere version.